# Reading off coefficients as array

Tags: list-manipulation, series-expansion, code-request

Suppose I have a series expansion with non-associative characters, i.e.,
$1**2**3**4**5  + 2**3**4**5**1 + \cdots$

Then I want to make some array which produces
$A[1]= \{1,2,3,4, 5\}, A[2]=\{2,3,4,5,1\}, \cdots $ Is there any nice command for this?  I am considering the arbitrary length. i.e., $1**2*3**4**5**6**7**8**9 \cdots + $ as an input and reading ordered coefficients like above.

Comment: `NestList[RotateLeft, Range@#, #] &[5]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
expr = Plus @@ (NonCommutativeMultiply @@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, #] & /@ 
   RandomInteger[{2, 9}, 3])
```

> ```
>    6 ** 10 ** 5 ** 4 + 
>    10 ** 1 ** 4 ** 3 ** 3 ** 7 + 
>     9 ** 1 ** 1 ** 2 ** 1 ** 2 ** 9 ** 4
> ```

```
 List @@@ List @@ expr
```

> ```
>  {{6, 10, 5, 4}, {10, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7}, {9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9, 4}}
> ```

You can also replace `Plus` and `NonCommutativeMultiply` with `List`:

```
expr /. Plus | NonCommutativeMultiply -> List
```

> ```
> {{6, 10, 5, 4}, {10, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7}, {9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9, 4}}
> ```

Comment: thanks Now I can read coefficients easily!